# Prevent button from becoming transparent when selected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-button

I have a `recyclerview` that has a  row of buttons. My objective is to make the currently selected button have text that is teal-colored, while the rest have text that is grey colored.

To do that, I have the following code in my `TabAdapter` class:

```
class TabAdapter(private val items: ArrayList<Pair<String, ArrayList<String>>>, private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TabViewHolder>() {
private var selectedPosition: Int = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TabViewHolder {
    return TabViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabrecycler_item_column, parent, false))
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TabViewHolder, position: Int) {

    context as AnimeFaceKeyboard

    holder.itemView.isSelected = selectedPosition == position

    if (holder.itemView.isSelected) {
        holder.button.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.material_deep_teal_200))
    } else {
        holder.button.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.material_grey_600))
    }


    //This code sets the widths of the buttons to, at minimum,
    //occupy the entire width of the screen combined 
    val displayMetrics = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics

    if (itemCount * (120 * displayMetrics.density) < displayMetrics.widthPixels) {
        holder.button.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels / itemCount
    }


    holder.button.text = items[position].first
    holder.button.setOnClickListener {

        //TODO - Figure out how this code works
        notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition)
        selectedPosition = holder.layoutPosition
        notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition)

        //This code updates a different recyclerview. 
        context.isFavoritesTabSelected = position == items.lastIndex
        context.updateCurrentImageLayout(items[position].second)
    }
}

}
class TabViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
val button: Button = view.tabButton

}
```

The relevant lines are in the `onBindViewHolder` method. Specifically this line

```
holder.itemView.isSelected = selectedPosition == position
```

and this code inside the `onClick` method for the buttons

```
        notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition)
        selectedPosition = holder.layoutPosition
        notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition)
```

Also here is the layout for the buttons in the `recyclerview`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tabButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minWidth="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Unset-Button-Text"
        android:background="@color/darkshade"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The behavior of my `recyclerView` is partially function. The text of the currently selected button, is in fact, teal colored.

However, there are two issues

1] The buttons turn partially transparent when they are tapped. Something must be wrong with the on-tap ripple animation

and

2] The ripple animation is only supposed to play for the current button that is selected, but, it also plays for the previously selected button.

Here is a GIF from my phone to demonstrate:

[image: Video_Of_Phone]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @Shashwat's answer, I solved the problem by changing the background color of the `recyclerview` to the same color as the buttons.

This means that even if the adapter recreates the button from scratch, there is no fading in and out.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, these lines are causing the problem

```
    notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition)
    selectedPosition = holder.layoutPosition
    notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition)
```

The previously selected button is blinking because you're calling `notifyItemChanged()` on it to unselect it and the adapter recreates it from scratch to update it.
Then, the same thing is happening with the currently selected button, being recreated from scratch to update changes on UI.

You can try implementing TabLayout because a layout like this would work best if you use tabs instead of RecylerView.

Comment: If my answer helped you, can you please mark it as correct?